# Kafka connect - ElasticsearchSinkConnector read messages in 1 minute interval only

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka-connect(`confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.0`) with `io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector` with this configuration:

```
{
  "name": "parcel${connector-name-suffix}-elasticsearch-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "linger.ms": "1",
    "topics": "${topics}",
    "topic.key.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "${elasticsearch-url}",
    "connection.username": "${elasticsearch-username}",
    "connection.password": "${elasticsearch-password}",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "transforms": "extractValue,createKey,extractKey",
    "transforms.extractValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.extractValue.field": "object",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "id",
    "transforms.extractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractKey.field": "id",

    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"${topics}-dlq",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 3,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":true
  }
}
```

rest configuration is the default.

My problem is that currently sink saves new messages from Kafka in 1-minute intervals. It looks like `"linger.ms": "1"` is ignored and I don't understand what is wrong.

EDIT1:
In logs I can see that kafka-connect commits offset after 1 minute:

```
[2021-08-12 06:26:45,184] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-connector-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1141: {topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3687724, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-08-12 06:27:45,184] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-connector-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1142: {topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3687768, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-08-12 06:28:45,184] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-connector-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1143: {topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3687808, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
```

Comment: `linger.ms: 1` is one **millisecond**, not "minutes", so not ignored, but definitely "unnoticeable". Otherwise, sounds like you want to adjust the consumer `max.poll.records` or similar properties that actually affect how many records end up being sent with the ES client. But, you really shouldn't want to send single messages 
 / many small batches immediately upon consumption as this will heavily impact your ES server's performance

Comment: `linger.ms: 1` it's the default for this connector - from doc I assume that it should index messages in default batches 20k or after 1ms.

Comment: How do you know that connect is writing new messages in 1-minute intervals? Remember that documents in ElasticSearch only become visible to search when the index 'refresh window' has passed. They are 'in' ES, just not searchable.

Comment: I can see lag on `elasticsearch-sink-connector` consumer group. It increases constantly and after exactly one minute it becomes zero again and new documents are visible